# Many subscriptions to a single queue with RabbitMQ STOMP

Tags: rabbitmq, stomp

Is it possible to bind a single queue to many topics using RabbitMQ STOMP client?
Each time a client sending SUBSCRIBE frame server creates a new queue for it, it makes usage of "prefetch-count" useless for me, because it applies to each subscription individually.
I am just looking for any way to get messages with many topics in the single queue via RabbitMQ Web-STOMP. Any ideas?

Comment: can you show us some of your code?

Comment: There was nothing special in my code. This time I've changed design of my app, but the question is how to bind one queue to many routing keys in RabbitMQ using its STOMP adapter. Currently the server creates new queue when receives SUBSCRIBE frame, but it is not the RabbitMQ style, as far as I understand it.

Comment: If this can help, this two frames will cause creation of two different queues:

Comment: SUBSCRIBE
id:worker-1
destination:/topic/topic-A
ack:client-individual

Comment: SUBSCRIBE
id:worker-1-2
destination:/topic/topic-B
ack:client-individual

Comment: The "id" field is required to be unique per session.

Comment: This is exactly what I am looking for. Any luck since then ?

Comment: No, but there is node.js and web sockets, since it works fine RabbitMQ is needed no more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See Documentation:[User generated queue names for Topic and Exchange destinations](https://www.rabbitmq.com/stomp.html#d.ugqn)

The header `x-queue-name` specified queue name should binding to same queue if there exist, but will exist multiple subscription on client.

The different between AMQP and STOMP concept not compatible in some ways.

Comment: This is the feature of version 3.5.7 released 15 December 2015, I asked in 2012, but thank you :)